# Dynamically adjust the width of select box

Tags: html

Instead of fixing the width of the select dropdown with px, can it be possible to dynamically change the width of the select box depending on the options selected. so for instance depending on the day the select box will resize.

```
  <select name="day"  class="activity-filter"  >
        <option value="/customer/8708?day=Any+Day">Any Day</option>
        <option value="/customer/8708?day=Mon">Monday</option>
        <option value="/customer/8708?day=Tue">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="/customer/8708?day=Wed">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="/customer/8708?day=Thu">Thursday</option>
        <option value="/customer/8708?day=Fri">Friday</option>
        <option value="/customer/8708?day=Sat">Saturday</option>
        <option value="/customer/8708?day=Sun">Sunday</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: With pure CSS, I don't think so. You'd probably have to use some JavaScript to resize the input on each state change. Why would you ever want that to happen anyway?